# Spring Boot : update same field inside array objects

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to update the "fileName" field inside the Documents array. What I want is to update all the fileName values inside the documents array with the same value.

```
{
        "id": "2312",
        "created_by" : "21",
        "title": "TestDoc1",
        "documents": [
            {
                "fileId": "1",
                "fileName": "hello.txt",
            },
            {
                "fileId": "2",
                "fileName": "testing2.xlsx",
            },
            {
                "fileId": "3",
                "fileName": "testing3.docx",          
            }
        ]
}
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
   {
            "id": "2312",
            "created_by" : "21",
            "title": "TestDoc1",
            "documents": [
                {
                    "fileId": "1",
                    "fileName": "removed",
                },
                {
                    "fileId": "2",
                    "fileName": "removed",
                },
                {
                    "fileId": "3",
                    "fileName": "removed",          
                }
            ]

    }
```

I have tried the following code.

```
 public void update(final String uID) {
    
    Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("created_by").is(uID));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("documents.fileName", "removed");
    System.out.println(mongoTemplate.updateMulti(query, update, Assignment.class));

}
```

Error : `Cannot create field 'fileName' in element`

The operation works when

```
update.set("documents.0.fileName", "removed");
```

But it only works for the 1st object of the array. I've tried the following as well, which results in a error

```
update.set("documents.$.fileName", "removed");
```

Error : `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query`

I'm relatively new to MongoDB & SpringBoot. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#mongodb-update-up.---

use  "$[]" operator for updating all values in array

Comment: @Lucia thank you it worked! The issue was with not adding the "[]", only "$"